# what's the differenct amone a tcp connection, socket connection and a http connection?

Tags: sockets, http, tcp, udp

It seems that many "connection" concept exist. such as socket connection, tcp connection and http connection.

so, what the difference?

Comment: A "connection" is merely a step during communications which follow some protocol. A pair of internet protocol "sockets" (one client, one listener) would typically be the basis for the communication onto which you could layer other protocols (e.g: TCP over IP, HTTP over TCP, etc).

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_protocol_suite

Comment: What is the difference between a wheel, a car, and a transportation company?

Answer (score 2):

They're different degrees of specialization: an HTTP connection is a type of TCP connection is a type of socket connection.

Comment: In particular, a TCP connection is a type of socket connection over which both parties expect all data to be received (vs. [UDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol), over which some data loss is expected). HTTP is one of thousands of protocols that [applications use](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_layer) to format the data they send over a TCP connection.

Answer (score -2):

For two entities to communicate they need a hook to each other to pass messages across - These hooks are sockets. We can say they are identities of the process. Communication b/w these sockets would be over a socket connection.

Now, how does one send messages and receive messages? Who decides to open a connection request to a socket, how does one close. Many questions arise isn't? Here comes the your TCP. By following the rules put forth by TCP, applications engage in a message exchange using TCP protocol over the sockets. Now you can refer to them as TCP connection.

Now, it need not be just stream of data bytes that the two applications exchange using the TCP protocol and b/w the two sockets. Applications can define their own protocol - Like - `I am looking for a content - do you have it? - Yes, here it is`. One such applications defined protocol is HTTP. The web page of SO that you used your browser to read is over HTTP- TCP - and two sockets belonging to SO server and your browser.

Comment: This post is not wrong, but it's a little verbose without directly answering the question. Needs editing.

Comment: I would really like to know in what ways the post deserves down-vote and eligible for deletion. I would like to correct my mistakes. I have put in rudimentary terms which I think is apt given how the questions was simplistically and generically framed. I am open to criticisms. So, @downvoters, request you to provide me the reason.